# Using Spark in Scala in intellij IDE

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

[image]So I want to use Scala on Intellij and do some spark programs but I keep getting the error

Cannot resolve symbol apache.

This keeps coming for the majority of the imports I do like:

An error for every import. Please help me because I am not sure of the dependency or how exactly spark works in SCALA.
(I am trying scala as I have already done in pyspark and I know it). Thank you

I saw a couple of youtube videos , some said to download Maven and use sbh instead. I need a clear cut understanding of how I can work with scala on any IDE besides terminal.

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

Comment: Please add screenshots or exception details ..

Comment: Did you setup Maven or SBT? If not, I recommend you do it, it will be way easier to manage dependencies. It's roughly like pip in Python.

Comment: Ive added the screenshot of what I am trying to do. I am not sure what to do and which one I should use, sbt or intellij. Also I cant see Maven in build system. What does that mean